# Proving the common positive divisor that is a linear combination of the two numbers must be the GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers. Suppose that $d$ is a positive common divisor of $x$ and $y$ such that $d \in \mathbb Zx+\mathbb Zy$. Prove that $d= \gcd(x, y)$.

I am reviewing some number theory before my class in the fall and this problem was in the book. I know that if $d$ is a common divisor it must divide both $x$ and $y$, so $x=dk$ and $y=dl $ for some integers $k$ and $l$. I also know this is similar to Bezout's lemma but I am not sure how to solve it. Any help?

Comment: It falls out directly from the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof) of Bézout’s lemma.

Comment: Bezout Lemma says that if $k \in \mathbb Zx +\mathbb Zy$ then $\gcd(x,y)|k$.  So if $d\in \mathbb Zx + \mathbb Zy$ then $\gcd(x,y)|d$ and $\gcd(x,y) \le d$.  But $gcd(x,y)$ is the *greatest* common divisor so $d\le \gcd(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $d \in \mathbb Z x + \mathbb Z y$ there are $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ so that $d = ax+by$.

But $\gcd(x,y)$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $y$ so $\gcd(x,y)$ divides $ax+by = d$ so $\gcd(x,y)$ divides $d$.

But you should know that all common divisors of $x,y$ divide $\gcd(x,y)$.  So we have $\gcd(x,y)|d$ and $d|\gcd(x,y)$ and (as they are both positive) that means $d=\gcd(x,y)$.

Don't know that theorem of all common divisors of $x,y$ divide $\gcd(x,y)$?  That's okay.  $\gcd(x,y)$ is the *greatest* common divisor so $d \le \gcd(x,y)$.  But $\gcd(x,y)|d$ and as they are both positive, nothing positive can divide anything positive that is *smaller* than itself.  $\gcd(x,y ) \le d$.

So $d = \gcd(x,y)$.

=====

Lemma: If $m,k > 0$ and $m|k$ and $k|m$ then $m =k$.

Pf: $m|k$ so there is an integers $j$ so that $mj=k$.  And $k|m$ so there is an integer $h$ so that $kh = m$  so $kh = m$ and $khj = mj = k$  so $hj=1$.  So $h=j = \pm 1$.  And we can rule out that $h=j=-1$ and $m$ and $k$ are both positive.

Lemma:  If $m,k > 0$ and $m|k$ then $m \le k$.

Pf:  If $m|k$ then $\frac km$ is a positive integer.  So $\frac km \ge 1$.  So $k\ge m$.

=====

Theorem (often a definition):  If $d|x$ and $d|y$ then $d|\gcd(x,y)$.

Pf: Well Bezout's lemma does it best.  There are integers $j,k$ so that $\gcd(x,y) = jx + ky$ but $d|x,y$  so $d|jx + ky =\gcd(x,y)$

But can do it without Bezout's Lemma by considering $x = md = k\gcd(x,y)$ for some $m,d$ and $y = nd = j\gcd(x,y)$ for some $nj$.  And if $d\not \mid \gcd(x,y)$ then then $d$ and $k$ have for factors in common as do $d$ and $j$ and if you multiply those factors by $\gcd(x,y)$ then you get a common divisor larger than the greatest common divisor.  But that's really tedious and is a variable naming nightmare.